# Laravel passport global clients

Tags: php, oauth, laravel-passport

I have a Laravel user database (> 14k customers) and would like to authenticate and authorize all users accross multiple websites of our company (2-5 Laravel and .NET webs) from a single OAUTH server.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport seems to document only workflow when "OAUTH clients" are added per user (witch nice and also a requirement), but I want to have global "clients" available for all users. I dont want my users to be able to remove their access to other websites of our company and even more be required to add it one by one in order to use it.

Workflow:

User comes to one of company sites (1.company.com, 2.company.com, 3.company.com...) and is redirected to server **oauth.company.com** and after successful login redirected to the original target website.

User can add aditional clients, but are not required to add **1.company.com** or other sites of our network.

Is that even possible with passport?